# Issues with variable echos

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is that i created a little username input
And my variable in javascript does not assign to the html input box

So my html is :-

```js
let username;



document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {

  //i think that the problem is here, where the name gets assigned

  username = document.getElementById("textarea").value;



}
console.log(username)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
   
</head>
<body>
   
<label> create a username </label>

<input id = "textarea"><hr>
<button id = "submit">submit</button>  


<script src=index.js></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried changing the variable to name, username, first name etc. But it didn't work

Then i tried changing the id's but that didn't work either
It always says "undefined"

Comment: `head` element must not contain visible elements.

Comment: Ok, let me try moving it to body and see if it works

Comment: just move your console.log inside the onclick function and it will work fine

Comment: Ok let me try it

Comment: it works fine, move the `console.log` to the end of the onclick function

Comment: It worked! Thank you! But i would like to know what was the difference between putting console.log inside and outside of onclick?

Comment: @volty see my answer for the explanation on how js executes the instructions

Comment: The problem is your are console.logging before anything is clicked.  Since it's before it logs as undefined.

Comment: Ok, but can i console log username after it is clicked and outside of the curly brackets?

Comment: @Volty no. You have to do it inside your onclick function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed your html and moved the console.log after the username has been defined and it works as expected

```js
let username;



document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {

  //i think that the problem is here, where the name gets assigned

  username = document.getElementById("textarea").value;

  console.log(username)

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>username</title>

</head>
<body>
  <label> create a username </label>



  <input id="textarea">
  <hr>

  <button id="submit">submit</button>

  <script src=index.js></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Your original js code can be read like this:

1. create a new variable with no value assigned.
2. console.log the variable: it returns undefined;
3. add an event listner to the code, assign the value to the variable but do not echo it.

Instead, the fixed one does:

1. create a new variable with no value assigned.
2. add an event listner to the code, assign the value to the variable;
3. echo it only after it is assigned.

Comment: in the scope of the question, the issue is not reproducible. The value is assigned to the variable correctly. As such it should not be answered but commented on and closed as such.

Comment: Can you please tell me ehat is event listener and echo?

Comment: @tacoshy the question was posed wrong and is on the sequence js uses to execute instructions. thus is not to be closed as a typo

Comment: @Volty the event listner is the .onclick function. the echo is the console.log

Comment: the questions ask about the variable assignment. That the console.log is never executed and as such is not visible was not content of the question at any point. That merely lead to a misconclusion by the OP.